# Monitor output from Netbeans C/C++ in command promt

Tags: c, cmd, netbeans-7

one year ago i was dealing with a C project and using Netbeans C/C++ and i want see the output which when we compile an C code you know it creates an .exe file and when we run it a black screen shows up for the output so i want to use same thing (i guess we call cmd) when i use Netbeans C/C++ when i run the programme.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are looking up for this: http://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2009/03/01/how-to-attach-a-console-to-your-gui-app-in-c/

Comment: i guess i asked the wrong thing. the question is i want to see my output on screen which when we usually compile a C code it creates an .exe file and when we click to that file runs on a blackscreen which is same as with command prompt screen. am i clear _?